# select maximum n records from table with at most one record per group

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have a table with a simple schema: `user_id`, `score` and I would like to extract the n records with the highest score, such that each `user_id` is only represented once.

This question is similar to [Get top n records for each group of grouped results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12113699/get-top-n-records-for-each-group-of-grouped-results) except that instead of needing n representatives per group, I need n representatives of the table, with a maximum of one record per group.

As such, if i'm looking for n=3, running the query on:

```
user_id | score
      1 |    10
      2 |     9
      1 |    11
      2 |     8
      3 |     8
      4 |    12
```

should yield:

```
user_id | score
      4 |     12
      1 |     11
      2 |      9
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT user_id, MAX(score) FROM table GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY MAX(score) DESC LIMIT 3;
```

Comment: oh wow, i was gymnasting through self joins and subqueries and all that stuff, so glad it has an easy solution!

Comment: @Mala: Then you are still thinking `RBAR - Row By Agonizing Row`. Instead learn to think `column by column`; in this case, max score for top 3 users leads quickly to this solution.

Comment: If I added a date column to the table, how could I extend this to return the correct date? The trivial extension of selecting the date as well returns the first date instead of the date connected with the max score